# Looking for non-zero property TOs: Can I match a Description with number property, but use a regex match?

Tags: regex, qtp, hp-uft

**How can I -without iterating, i.e. by using `.ChildObjects`- match all test objects with any non-zero value in a number property?**

Contained question: **Can I match, using a regex match, a property value that contains a `number` (i.e. `VarType` returns 3 (`vbLong`) for the getROProperty value of this property) using a regex match?** I don't think so.

For example:

```
Dim Descr: Descr=Description.Create
Descr ("micclass").Value="WebElement"
Descr ("height").Value=11
```

matches some controls in my web application, i.e. `Page.ChildObjects (Descr).Count > 0`.

But assigning the `11` as a string, i.e. changing the height line to:

```
Descr ("height").Value="11"
```

matches zero controls.

*This is quite bad, since consequently, I am unable to look for test objects with `height` not equal to 0. That would've been exactly what I need.*

I'd use

```
Descr ("height").Value="^[1-9][0-9]*$"
Descr ("height").RegularExpression=true
```

to search for all instances with nonzero `height` values, but since the string search does not match, the regex match won´t work, too. (In fact, it indeed doesn´t).

Comment: There's something odd going on there then, as specifying height as a string works fine and matches the relevant elements for me.

Comment: Which particular UFT version and browser type & version are you trying this on? I'm trying to think why it works for me and not you.

Comment: QTP 11.00 build 1018, IE 9.0.8112.16421

Comment: Good to know I do have a reason to wonder.

Comment: @Xiaofu Are you sure it works for you? Also see the answer comments.

Comment: Very sure. I tried on UFT 11.52 on Win7 when I originally commented, and have tried again just now with that and also QTP 11.00 on XP. They both seem happy passing in numbers or strings to the Description object and finding results in exactly the same way you have typed above. I'll try out the regex...

Comment: Regex + Description object does indeed appear to behave insanely in this scenario though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It is known](http://relevantcodes.com/qtp-all-about-the-description-object-description-create/) that integer types has to be passed as integers in the description rendering the usage of regular expressions useless unfortunately.

I do not have a QTP installation at hand right now, but to investigate it further, what happens if you use

```
Print Browser("myBrowser").WebElement("height:=11").ChildObjects.Count
```

and

```
Print Browser("myBrowser").WebElement("height:=^[1-9][0-9]*$").ChildObjects.Count
```

Where `"myBrowser"` is your browser definition of course.

Comment: Will check. Nice idea. If that works, I´d consider the fact that my "10" does not match a bug...

Comment: OK. At least it is consistent. "Height:=11" works fine. "height:=<regex>" does not work, never finds anything, even with ".*" as the regex. So descriptive programming descriptions are behaving exactly like descriptions created with Description.Create: A non-string property value cannot be matched to a regular expression.

Comment: Probably when using an object like `xxx.WebElement(something)`  QTP/UFT first looks for the vartype of `something`. If it is an object, it assumes it is a `Object Description`; if it is a string it first looks in the Object Repository to see if it is defined there and if not, it tries to create an Description with the values in `something`.

Comment: Now it seems what is "known" is true.